# Mixpanel: OptinTracking a user deletes profile properties (after optout)

Tags: android, mixpanel

We are using mixpanel to track some events in our android app. Everything works fine and the users have the profile properties.
When a user optsout tracking and then decides to optin tracking again the identify works fine but the user hasn't any profile property. (it seems like they were deleted -- even mixpanel's default are not shown)

Android SDK:

optout:

```
 mixpanel.track("EventName",someProps);
 mixpanel.flush();
 mixpanel.optOutTracking();
```

optin:

```
 mixpanel.optInTracking();
 mixpanel.identify(user.getNickname());
 mixpanel.track("EventName",someProps);
 mixpanel.flush();
```

Any ideas why is this happening?